# Storing SSH passphrases for a session

Tags: linux, ssh, debian

So I recently moved from Ubuntu to Debian and noticed that after I authenticate via typing in my passphrase for my private ssh key, I still need to enter it again if I connect elsewhere. Ubuntu used to remember it for everything until I killed my session. Any ideas on how to get this back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an SSH agent. In Ubuntu, you were probably using GNOME Keyring. This makes it rather easy to automatically add your SSH key once upon login.

There are other methods available, though I don't know what's available in Debian. For example, a program called [Keychain](http://www.funtoo.org/wiki/Keychain) will automatically add your key on each successive login to a terminal; you only need to enter your password once.

Finally, there is the manual method. After opening a new TTY or PTY (that is, a terminal or a virtual terminal emulator), just use the `ssh-add` command to add your key, and then just do all SSH-related tasks in that terminal.